# NoMethodError Occurred, undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, methods, null

First of all, I know it has been posted, I've seen most of the question posts but I still don't understand how it works.

So I'm getting the error:

```
Script 'Terrain Tag Detection ~' line 115: NoMethodError occurred.

undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

My 'Terrain Tag Detection ~' Script looks like this: http://pastebin.com/PUypTwJs (can't paste the code here correctly, and yes it's about Pokemon).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means your `@map = WildPokemon.fetch($game_map.map_id)` method doesn't return and value and you want to access @map variable.

You can add a check in your code like below:

```
@map = WildPokemon.fetch($game_map.map_id)
if @map.present?
    @enemy = @map[0][rand(@map[0].size)]
    @level = @map[1][rand(@map[1].size)]
end
```

Comment: The main problem is: the script works but only works when map_id is 001.  Once the number changes it shows that error. Any idea?

Comment: That means you don't have any WildPokemon associated other map_ids

Comment: Found, fixed and understood! Thanks!